"Mosaico Templates" and "Mosaico settings" menu are not visible
I take over a CiviCRM installation (latest version 5.72.1) under WordpPress (6.5.2) with Mosaico extension (version3.5.1709296836).
I don't understand why "Mosaico Templates" and "Mosaico settings" menu are not visible. I try to restore di CiviCRM navigation menu, but without any effect.
Does anyone have any idea what the reason might be? Or how to investigate?
I tried the same versions locally (but not the same db and extensions) and the menus show up.
Thanks

Does it work if you visit the url manually? If not, you could try visiting civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

Yes, the links work correctly and I already tried to rebuid the menu. Do I try to disable the extensions one at a time?

You could just go to admin - customize - navigation and create the menu entries.

:-) sure, but I wanted to understand why.

After uninstalling and reinstalling Mosaico the menus appeared.
These are the commands I have executed:
cv ext:disable mosaico
cv ext:uninstall mosaico
cv ext:install mosaico


Thanks! I had exactly the same problem and fixed it by re-installing via the web interface. The downside is that it wipes out all your existing templates.
